# Detect URL tags example.com/page.php#anycontent

Tags: php

How can I identify this type of tags:

`example.com/file.php#inbox` or `example.com/another.php#spam`

Like Gmail is detecting `#inbox` `#spam` `#mycontent`

I have tried with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` but it does not work...

Comment: What exactly have you tried with `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`? Can you show us some code?

Comment: it's name is hash, you can trigger hash change by javascript, using jquery will be helpful. http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Comment: @smott REQUEST_URI is only going to have /file.php

Comment: You can send the info by ajax

Answer (score 3):

The hash part (everything after and including the `#` character) is not sent to the server. Only the client side (javascript) can read and use it.

The hash property can be requested from the Javascript `location` objects: `location.hash`.

If you want to pass data to a page, use GET parameters:

```
page.php?key=value
```

In PHP, you can use `$_GET['key']` to retrieve `value`.